# How can 802.11p ensure 1 Mbps in 1 km range?

Tags: communication-standard

Using the 802.11p standard, mobile vehicles can communicate each other.

IEEE 802.11p standard typically uses channels of 10 MHz bandwidth in the 5.9 GHz band (5.850-5.925 GHz).

And the transmission power is typically 20 mW.

In BPSK OFDM and 1/2 code rate of 802.11p standard documents, data rate of 802.11p is 3 Mbps. But in some overview, the 1 Mbps is ensured in 1 km transmission range.

Is the data rate is changed in the real environment?

If so, how was the data rate 1 Mbps calculated?

Comment: It is not uncommon that the real data rate is below the marketing peak rate. Many factors need to be taken into account such as channel characteristics, pathloss, interference, etc and also the meaning of the fancy word "ensured".

Comment: also things "data rate" is treacherous: pre or post channel decoding? Including header data or without? Assuming continuous transmission or actually implemented collision avoidance? At which tolerable bit error rate? Using which antennas?

Comment: In short: you can't compare two different systems unless you specify in which ways they differ and in which ways they don't. Imagine comparing someone with a satellite dish for communications to someone with a chip antenna!